# How to use cross domain dynamically generated CSS

Tags: php, css, cross-domain, cdn

I'm attempting to minimize and cache all of our CSS files on our server. I have a script that runs quite well but only works locally and our CSS files are hosted on a CDN. It's a dynamically generated CSS file and the link to it looks like this:

> http://mysite.com/style/apiconnect,ui,ui_typography,ui_lists,ui_forms,ui_datatables,help,tutorials,achievementUnlocked,styles,content,calendar_select,common,content_print

Each item is a different css file that gets loaded by the php script in the back minimized and cached as appropriate. That all works great but our main site can't use it. `<link href="http://mysite/link" />` doesn't work as it doesn't load at all.

I've set header types as:

```
header("Content-Type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

And nothing the main site won't load it. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://url" type="text/css" />
```

to include style sheets.

`<link rel="http://url">` is an invalid method to include styles. See also: [MDN: `<link>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/link)

Comment: Whoops I did that by accident.. that doesn't work either.. Let me edit that.

Comment: Inspect your request. Is the file correctly served using MIME type `text/css`? Does the file exist? Is the CSS actually valid? **EDIT: Your question code has been updated. But you did still not include the `rel` and `type` attribute**.